# Android application hosting places? Where all apps to be hosted?

Tags: android, release

I am about to release my first Android application. I dont know where all I need to release it other than google play store. What do usually developers do? Any inputs? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can release in Amazon Market Place, and you can also host the app through Get Jar

Here are some [Alternates to Google Play Store](http://thenextweb.com/apps/2011/01/09/6-alternatives-to-the-android-market/) and [Some Others](http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/android-app-stores/)

Comment: If you think the answer is useful, please consider of accepting it:)

Comment: sure. yesterday that was within 10 minutes.. thats y didnt accep